# Error inflating class com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout

Tags: android

I'm using [umano's SlidingUpPanel library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in my project, but when I tried to run the app, an `InflateException` was raised.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
```

This is my layout

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_main"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- other layout -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

And this is my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.8'
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you find the strack trace in Logcat? Generally there are more details on what exactly went wrong there. Based on what I can see, it looks like you may have forgotten to set the mandatory attribute `android:gravity="bottom|top"` (choose one), or perhaps you mixed it up with the currently set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` attribute?

Comment: You are right @MH. I used auto-complete so I didn't really pay attention. Can you please move your comment to answers section so I can mark it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per earlier comment:

Based on what I can see, it looks like you may have forgotten to set the mandatory attribute `android:gravity="bottom|top"` (choose one), or perhaps you mixed it up with the currently set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` attribute?

The correct gravity attribute should be set somewhat like this:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout 
    ...
    android:gravity="bottom"
    ...
>

...

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```